# Pentaho SQL to MongoDb - Array Issue

Tags: sql, arrays, mongodb, pentaho

I need to update elements in an array, then, when I run the transformation at the first time, the array receives the righ numbers if elements in the PROD array. But if I run it again, the array will receives the same elements

Example:

At the first time, I got the document below, and It is correct:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e2c81f781a75592f69f8a5"),
    "DDATA_ORC" : ISODate("2016-08-02T03:00:00.000Z"),
    "SNUMORC" : "113239",
    "PROD" : [ 
        {
            "SPRODUTO" : "TONER HP CE411A CIANO (305A)"
        }
    ]
}
```

But if I run the transformation again, the PROD array will be updated with the same SPRODUTO:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e2c81f781a75592f69f8a5"),
    "DDATA_ORC" : ISODate("2016-08-02T03:00:00.000Z"),
    "SNUMORC" : "113239",
    "PROD" : [ 
        {
            "SPRODUTO" : "TONER HP CE411A CIANO (305A)"
        }, 
        {
            "SPRODUTO" : "TONER HP CE411A CIANO (305A)"
        }
    ]
}
```

It is a problem because I will get wrong results for queries.

That is may plugin configurations:
[Options Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgpXH.png) and [Document Path tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3FHn.png)

I need to update the array only if It receives or lose an item.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.

If anyone have this problem, the solution is to create 2 "MongoDB Output". In the first output, you need to set the array (the array will be recreated every time that the update query runs sucessfuly) . I did It using a dummy field.

[First Output Document Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwqx4.png)

In the second "MongoDB Output", You need to execute a push to populate the array.

[Second Output Document Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPnRq.png)

In the "Output Options" tab, You have to set Update, Upsert and "Modifier Update"